# How to get the decimal symbol?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsnumberformatter

I want to get which is the decimal symbol set up on the device. Until now I was using this method:

```
NSString *decimalSymbol;     
NSNumberFormatter *f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];    
[f setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];   
[f setMinimumFractionDigits:2];     
[f setMaximumFractionDigits:2];     
[f setGroupingSeparator:@" "];      

NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];    
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];   
[formatter setMinimumFractionDigits:2];     
[formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];     
[formatter setGroupingSeparator:@" "];      

NSRange range = {1,1};  

decimalSymbol = [[formatter stringFromNumber:[f numberFromString:[@"" stringByAppendingFormat:@"%.02f", 1.0f]]] substringWithRange:range];  

[formatter release];    
[f release];
```

It was working fine until now when I am testing on another device (4.3) - `null` is returned.
What could be the problem?

Is there another way to retrive the decimal symbol?

LATER EDIT:
I can use:

```
decimalSymbol = [[@"" stringByAppendingFormat:@"%.02f", 1.0f] substringWithRange:range];
```

but why the other way it doe not work on this particular device?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
NSString *decimalSymbol = [formatter decimalSeparator];
```

Answer (score 21):

The best way is get the decimal separator from the current locale without init any `NSNumberFormatter` object.
Like this:

```
[[NSLocale currentLocale] objectForKey:NSLocaleDecimalSeparator]
```

Comment: Or from iOS 10+, `[NSLocale currentLocale].decimalSeparator;`

Answer (score 13):

Swift 4 version:

```
Locale.current.decimalSeparator
```

Answer (score 6):

**Swift 4**

You can use `Locale.current.decimalSeparator` or `NSLocale.current.decimalSeparator`.

> The Swift overlay to the Foundation framework provides the Locale
>   structure, which bridges to the NSLocale class.

and

> use NSLocale when you need reference semantics or other
>   Foundation-specific behavior.

[NSLocale Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nslocale)

Answer (score 2):

decimalSeparator

Returns a string containing the character the receiver uses to represent decimal separators.

`- (NSString *)decimalSeparator`

Example:

decimalSymbol = [f decimalSeparator];